# Python request 502 due to load balancer

Tags: python, python-requests, load-balancing

Quick question here, I'm using python request lib to test a bunch of APIs we developed. When I target directly the server

```
url = 'http://10.10.1.10:1080/auth'
response = requests.post(url,data=payload)
```

it works fine I have a 200 status. But when I use our official api url I always have a 502

```
url = 'http://my.prodcution.url/auth'
response = requests.post(url,data=payload)
```

I guess that this is due to our load balancer (as we have lot of servers behind) but I cannot figure out how to fix that. Any ideas ?
Help will be much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: 5xx indicates it's a server error - may be the DNS isn't properly setup, or anything, in short the server is down/not been able to work properly.
You can look for the exact error in the load balancer's logs.

Answer (score 0):

had a proxy issues just needed to add proxies to my request